# Elementor page builder shortcode issue - unable to include external PHP file when using ob_start and ob_get_clean

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a weird problem when I try to include my custom wordpress plugin shortcode within elementor. Whenever I use an external php file there is no output.

This code is working fine:

```
// Shortcode Output function
function vergleichsplugin_output_frontend() 
{

        ob_start();

        echo '<div class="vergleichsplugin"></div>';

        return ob_get_clean();

}


/* Shortcodes */ 
add_shortcode('vergleichsplugin','vergleichsplugin_output_frontend');
```

But this doesn't produce any output at all (file path is correct):

```
// Shortcode Output function
function vergleichsplugin_output_frontend() 
{

    ob_start();


    $html = require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/vergleichsplugin/views/frontend/frontend.php'); 


    $html = $html.ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
}



/* Shortcodes */ 
add_shortcode('vergleichsplugin','vergleichsplugin_output_frontend');
```

content of frontend.php is the same:

```
echo '<p>Output</p>';
```

Comment: Why did you not use the do_shortcode() function to print shortcode output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
function vergleichsplugin_output_frontend() {
    ob_start();

    include(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/vergleichsplugin/views/frontend/frontend.php'); 

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('vergleichsplugin','vergleichsplugin_output_frontend');
```

Why wasnt your solution working?

in order to save the contents of you file to a variable with `require_once` or `include` you would need to return all your html in that file. something like:

```
// frontend.php

<?php

$html = "<h1>Some sample html</h1>";

return $html;

?>
```

Also this section is not valid:

```
    $html = $html.ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
```

Should be:

```
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
```

Since using a buffer you dont need to save the require to a variable as the html will be returned by `ob_get_clean`;

Comment: I would still be interested why my code above is not working if anyone knows.

Comment: @DanielResch I updated my answer with more info on why...

Comment: thank you so much, it is very important for me to know :)
-> makes perfect sence now, I never had to use buffers before, thank you